# rsync but with a difference

Tags: rsync, nas

I use my android phone to record my 4K videos.
Now, i want to auto transfer the files (from the DCIM folder) to my NAS folder as soon as the files are generated and delete the original files from my phone.

I know rsync can do this very efficiently, but will also delete the destination files as soon as i remove the recordings from my phone.

So is there a way that can do automatically:

1) transfer files from the phone to NAS

2) verify the transfer

3) delete the original files from the phone

Also, i can use termux app on android to do the CLI commands.

Comment: "_rsync [...] will also delete the destination files as soon as i remove the recordings_" why do you say this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `rsync` it will do exactly what you want.

```
rsync -a --remove-source-files *.mp4 remote:/target/
```

Unless you specifically include the `--delete` flag, it will not delete files on the target that are no longer present in the source.